# Recaptcha: Update Language

Tags: recaptcha

How do you update language for recaptcha.

I've tried with this options (like in the example) : lang : 'fr'

But it's not working.

Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that on CiviCRM 4.6.24.

Comment: Any new action on this - I can't get it to show e.g. a German version.

Answer (score 1):

The library in use in civicrm is not language aware. Here's a patch that is working for me on 5.27:

```
diff --git a/packages/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php b/packages/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php
index 78d2b14..c869a09 100644
--- a/packages/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php
+++ b/packages/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php
@@ -114,7 +114,8 @@ function recaptcha_get_html ($pubkey, $error = null, $use_ssl = false)
         } else {
                 $server = RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER;
         }
-
+        $locale = CRM_Core_I18n::getLocale();
+        $server = $server .'?hl='.$locale;
         $errorpart = "";
         if ($error) {
            $errorpart = "&amp;error=" . $error;
```

Comment: It would be nice to have this fixed in CiviCRM core - I've opened https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/issues/50 to discuss/track